# Laravel 6: Class 'Form' not found

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have a fresh Laravel 6 and I try to use Laravel forms but I got the error saying "Class 'Form' not found ".

I tried the followings but still not working:

1). Add this to composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~6.0"
}
```

2). update composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

3). add this to the providers of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
  // ...
  'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  // ...
],
```

4). Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
],
```

Please give advice because it works only with Laravel 5.8.

Comment: did you try to run `composer require laravelcollective/html` ?

Comment: Yes i did. But still error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First to install `laravelcollective` run this composer command 
`composer require laravelcollective/html`

or from your composer file in the `require` object

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0"
},
```

it should be `"laravelcollective/html": "^6.0"` not `"laravelcollective/html": "~6.0"`

and here is the new docs for laravel **v6.0** [link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#installation)

last thing: you don't need any more to include the package providers and aliases manually it will be added automatically

Comment: It works by running composer require laravelcollective/html